# Can I use KEEL in my java code?

Tags: machine-learning, weka

what i want is to use [KEEL](http://www.keel.es/)(Knowledge Extraction based on Evolutionary Learning) from my Java code? Like i use [WEKA](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code) from my Java or Python code.
I can't find something on the documentation. Is it possible such a thing?

Comment: I don't see the problem. it's an open source project - Just download the code and use it.

Comment: Ok that might be a great solution.

Comment: But i was wondering if there is some kind of an API to access it. thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but i'm guessing that the code will be divided to a framework and the windowed application which uses the framework.